# Limit of $\frac1n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_j$ if the series $\sum\limits_n \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose that $(a_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers such that 
series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}$ is convergent. 
 Show that the sequence: 
$$b_n=\frac{
\sum_{j=1}^n a_j}{n}$$ 
is convergent and find its limit.

I try to solve it by Stolz theorem, but no  success.

Source (http://vjimc.osu.cz/hist/j16problems1.pdf)

Comment: Got something from my answer?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Apply [Cesàro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean) to $$b_n=A_n-\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}A_j,\qquad A_j=\sum_{k=1}^j\frac{a_k}k.$$

Comment: Can anyone give more detail, please?

Comment: Sure--as soon as you explain what is blocking you.

Comment: Following Did's hint one should rewrite 
$b_n$ as $\frac{1}{n} (nA_n - \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}A_j)$ and try to find limit of the sequence $(nA_n - \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}A_j)$, but I can't do it.

Comment: No, one is not supposed to find the limit of $nA_n-\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}A_j$ (what gave you this idea?), simply the limit of $A_n-\frac1n\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}A_j$. That $A_n$ converges is a **hypothesis**. So what is left is to show that $\frac1n\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}A_j$ also converges and to identify its limit--and for this I provided the hint: **Cesàro**. (Say, did you check the link?)

Comment: Yes, I've checked the link. Thanks, Did, for details, now everything is clear.